# Redeclare struct in two Swift packages

Tags: swift

I created two different Swift packages that I use in several projects. Now I have to use both in the same project and my problem is, that I have a declared `struct` in both packages, that has exactly the same content and same name. But the compiler complains about that. Is there a possibility to tell the compiler, that these types are equal? I tried to use `typealias`, but then the compiler complains that he doesn't know where to look for the `struct`.

Comment: Declare it in just one package and use that as a dependency of whoever else needs it.

Comment: You can't use `Package1.MyStruct` and `Package2.MyStruct` to differentiate them? If not, what about using a third package, which will be "Core", "Common" which will hold that struct, and you'll use it as dependency of both the other packages?

Answer (score 0):

Like @matt and @Larme mentioned there are several possible solutions for your problem.

Swift is a module based language, hence you can use @Larme simple solution and differentiate the structs by using the package/module name as a prefix when importing.

According to my opinion @matt and @Larme latter suggestions are more to the point.
If you have two or more packages that are sharing the samr code. Why not creating a third package with that shared code and using it in both? A simple solution to your case would be a Models package where you can have the struct define there,  import and use it in Package1 and Package2.